# ASP.NET MVC5 CI/CD WIth Jenkins and Github

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- Merge code to Github
- Jenkins sees the merge and builds the project
- Deploy the project to IIS
- Navigate to website and see the updated changes.

Sorry if this has already been asked but I have searched all day for a up-to-date tutorial on how to implement continuous integration and delivery with Github, Jenkins, ASP.NET MVC5, and IIS server.

I am pretty new to CI/CD. Could one of you point me to a tutorial that works? I want to learn how to do this so if you have any links to good documentation on the matter, that would be great.

**Details:**

I am using code first migrations with entity framework 6.

SQL database, Jenkins, and IIS are all on the same server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Michel did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can install [github plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) to jenkins server. Set your server, credentials, project and hook settings(because of need to deploy when commited)
2. Create your deployment pipeline. You have your project source.
3. Install [msbuild](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) to server and prepare your deployment files.
4. Now you have deployment files, Use [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to stop app pool and web-site. https://gist.github.com/sdesalas/6533286
5. Use [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) to copy your files to server.
6. Use [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to start app pool and web-site.

Thats all. I hope this helps.